# Seeking a deeper Understanding of Inverse functions f(x) = 4 - x^2, x> or = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am seeking a deeper understanding of inverse functions

$$f(x) = 4 - x^2, x\geq0$$

How does the Domain affect how one evaluates the function?

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific ?

Comment: If find the inverse for f(x) I will get y= the square root of 4-x. What do I do after that?

Comment: Let $y=4-x^2$. Hense $x=(+or-)sqrt(4-y)$ The specification of the domain $x>0$ induces the right definition of $x(y)=+sqrt(4-y)$ : the case $-sqrt(4-y)$ is eliminated.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the domain there may or may not be an inverse function.
Let's recall the definition of a function :

> For each argument x, the corresponding unique y in the codomain is called the function value at x or the image of x under f.

So the matter is, does the inverse give a *unique* answer or multiple? In your example, $f(x) = 4-x^2$ the function will have two inverses on the domain $\mathbb R$ but a unique on $x\ge0$ as the function is strictly decreasing.

To check if there is a unique inverse, it's quite simple using a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%20-%20x%5E2). put a ruler horizontally on the plot, if it crosses the function multiple times, then it has multiple inverses so cannot be inverted. That is what happens if you take the whole real line.
Now if you restrict yourself to $x\ge0$, your ruler will only cross the plot on one point : it is invertible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it does not.

Long answer:

The domain is one of the elements that actually *defines* a function. Therefore, in the case of the function $f(x) = 4-x^2$, just sawing that that is $f$ is not enough to define $f$. You must also define the domain of $f$. In that sense, the function $f$ (which maps $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb R$) is not equal to the function $g(x) = 4-x^2$ which maps $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Now, what does this have to do with inverse functions, you say? Well, if you remember, a function $f: A\to B$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$ if *and only if* the function $f$ is bijective. So, is $f$ bijective? Clearly not, as for every $x$, the value of $f(x)$ is smaller than $4$, so there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=5$, for example. However, $f$ is *injective*. That means that $f$ is "almost" bijective, or more strictly, the function $f$, limited to the codomain $(-\infty, 4]$ is in fact bijective.

Very strictly speaking, you can take a look at $3$ functions here. Call them  $f,g,h$, where $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=4-x^2$, and where their domains are:
$$\text{domain}(f) = [0,\infty)\\
\text{domain}(g) = \mathbb R\\
\text{domain}(h) = [0,\infty)\\$$
$$\text{codomain}(f) = \mathbb R\\
\text{codomain}(g) = \mathbb R\\
\text{codomain}(h) = \mathbb (-\infty, 4]$$

Now, for these $3$ functions, you can say this:

- $g$ is not injective and not surjective
- $f$ is injective, but not surjevtive
- $h$ is both injective and bijective

Usually, in mathematics, you would say that more "quickly" by saying something like

> The function $4-x^2$ can be inverted if it is limited to the domain $[0,\infty)$. The domain of the inverse of the function is $(-\infty, 4]$.

(or similar), however it is important to realize that underneath that sentence, the real truth is

> There exists a function with a similar definition to $f$ which can be inverted. That function is defined by narrowing the domain of $f$ to $[0,\infty)$ and the codomain to $(-\infty,4]$

Answer (score 0):

Your inverse is going to be something like $f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt{4-y}$ for $y \le 4$.

This would not be the correct answer if the domain of the original function had been different, for example $x \lt 0$.  Instead it would have been $f^{-1}(y)=-\sqrt{4-y}$ for $y \lt 4$, with a sign change.

So the inverse can depend on the domain of the original function, and does so in an important way in this example.